# Passing URL in Codeigniter URL segment

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to pass a url like http://example.com/test?a=1&b=2 in url segment of codeigniter.

I'm trying to pass something like this http://myurl.com/abc/http://example.com/test?a=1&b=2 and get the "http://example.com/test?a=1&b=2" url. What should be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your URI protocol to `REQUEST_URI` in `application/config/config.php` , like this:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

then use `GET` method:

```
$this->input->get('a');
```

**EDIT:**

Since *http://example.com/test?a=1&b=2*  is not encoded URL, it isn't  possible. So first, I would encode URL with [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function like this:

```
urlencode('http://example.com/test?a=1&b=2');
```

it returns something like: `http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ftest%3Fa%3D1%26b%3D2`

So I would pass the URL like this:

```
http://myurl.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ftest%3Fa%3D1%26b%3D2
```

then get an example URL with GET method.

```
$this->input->get('url');
```

Comment: How would you do this without a get variable? Can you add it as a URI segmenent like so: `example.com/index.php/controller/method/var1/var2` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this technique to get the URL

```
$url = "http://example.com/test?a=1&b=2";
$segments = array($controller, $action, $url);
echo site_url($segments);

// or create a anchor link
echo anchor($segments, "click me");
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass urlendode()'d URL in segment and then decode it with own (MY_*) class:

application/core/MY_URI.php:

```
<?php

class MY_URI extends CI_URI {

    function _filter_uri($str)
    {
        return rawurldecode(parent::_filter_uri($str));
    }
}

// EOF
```