# CodeIgniter: urlencoded URL in URI segment does not work

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to put a URL as the value of one of my URI segments in CI. My controller method is defined to accept such an argument. However, when I go to the URL, I get a 404 error. For example:

www.domain.com/foo/urlencoded-url/

Any ideas what's wrong? Should I do this via GET instead?

**UPDATE:**

// URL that generates 404
`http://localhost/myapp/profile_manager/confirm_profile_parent_delete/ugpp_533333338/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2Fdashboard%2F`

// This is in my `profile_manager` controller
public function confirm_profile_parent_delete($encrypted_user_group_profile_parent_id = '', $url_current = '')

If I remove the second URI segement, I don't get a 404: `http://localhost/myapp/profile_manager/confirm_profile_parent_delete/ugpp_533333338/`

Comment: Can you post the specific URL and controller code?

Comment: Is the URL the method? or are you set up to leave off the method?  Otherwise, try /foo/method/variable i.e. /foo/index/url

Comment: is the encoded url generating characters that are not allowed in the CI URI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the %2F breaks things for apache.

Possible solutions:

1. preg_replace the /'s to -'s (or something else) before sending the url then switch it back on the other end.
2. Set apache to AllowEncodedSlashes On
3. bit of a hack, but you could even save the url to a session variable or something instead of sending through the url  *shrug *
4. double url encode it before sending

Comment: #1 is a pain, #2 means a reliance on server settings, and #3 just wont work for me as there would be too many URLs to put in session. Would it be the same problem if I made this a GET? I'll give it a try.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by making it a "Get" you are already sending it through the URL, no?  Anyway.. #1 doesn't seem like a pain to make 2 small helper functions to encode / decode the url and I think it's the best solution... however, the problem is actually being caused by the Apache server, not codeigniter, which is why the 2nd solution.   You can, however, try double url encoding the url before sending.

Answer (score 1):

Pass urlendode()'d URL in segment and then decode it with own (MY_*) class:

application/core/MY_URI.php:

```
class MY_URI extends CI_URI {

    function _filter_uri($str)
    {
        return rawurldecode(parent::_filter_uri($str));
    }
}

// EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the rule in config/route.php to accept the encoded characters in URL. Also you can take a look at some of the solution from below articles:

- http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/81365/
- http://sholsinger.com/archive/2009/04/passing-email-addresses-in-urls-with-codeigniter/
- [Passing URL in Codeigniter URL segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9848794/passing-url-in-codeigniter-url-segment)

Answer (score 0):

I actually had to do urlencode(urlencode(urlencode(

and urldecode(urldecode(urldecode(

3 times!! and it finally worked, twice didn't cut it.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted, it actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
function __autoload($class){
 if(!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])){
  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING'] = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] = $_SERVER['argv'][0]  = urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
}
}
```

in config.php
this method work for me

Answer (score 0):

This is very old, but I thought I'd share my solution.

Instead of accepting the parameter as a url path, accept it as a get variable:

```
http://localhost/myapp/profile_manager/confirm_profile_parent_delete/ugpp_533333338?url_current=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2Fdashboard%2F
```

and in code:

```
function confirm_profile_parent_delete($encrypted_user_group_profile_parent_id = '') {
    $url_current = $this->input->get('url_current');
    ...
```

This seems to work.