# Codeigniter encoded url fails on firefox/safari

Tags: php, codeigniter, firefox, safari

This seems like a VERY simple issue and I'm surprised I haven't been able to find ANY article (on any site) that addresses it...

When I enter an encoded version of a URL (to a CodeIgniter site) into Safari or Firefox, CodeIgniter returns a 404 error, but when I enter the SAME URL using Chrome or IE, it works...

Example: http://mediamonster.com.au/rmit%5F312/

Anyone have any idea why or how to fix it???

Comment: Its working for me on Firefox v50.0.0.2. Which version are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610799/codeigniter-urlencoded-url-in-uri-segment-does-not-work
Check this.

Comment: Hi @kishor10d - I'm using Firefox 42.0, but I've been getting complaints from various people who I assume all use different versions. I also get the same error on Safari. Just to be pedantic - would you mind trying to select the link on this page to see if you get a 404? [link](http://mediamonster.com.au/rmit_312/)